# org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am new to Jersey 2. So far I worked with Jersey 1.x and Spring and would like to use HK2 implementation.

After reading the [tutorial](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/) I wrote the following:

```
@ManagedBean
@Path("products")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class ProductResource {

    @Inject
    ProductManager productManager;

    @GET
    public GenericResponseData<List<Product>> getProducts(@QueryParam("condition") Condition condition, @QueryParam("keywords") String keywords) {
        GenericResponseData<List<Product>> res = new GenericResponseData<List<Product>>();
        res.setObject(productManager.getProducts(condition, keywords));
        return res;
    }

}
@Contract
public interface ProductManager {
    public List<Product> getProducts(Condition condition, String keywords);
}

@Service
public class MyProductManager implements ProductManager {
    @Override
    public List<Product> getProducts(Condition condition, String keywords) {
            return null;
        }
}
```

However I get the following exception:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I was playing around with JAXRS and @Inject-ing EJB and got same error. With @EJB it worked fine.

The solution was to add CDI configuration file and change bean-discovery-mode="annotated" to bean-discovery-mode="all"

After that I could use @Inject with my EJB.

This might help you also.

Comment: This solution stops raising the exception, but the injected object will be null!!! (At least for me)

Comment: Works for me with same erreor as poster and is what the spec says. Just forgot it in my beans.xml.

Comment: Is it possible to @Inject without a beans.xml file?  I would like to write the application using strictly Java configuration as I do with my Spring applications.

Comment: Just found you can use @RequestScoped annotation, e.g.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me., for those who want to know how to add it: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/cdi-adv001.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the @Service annotation above is the hk2 @Service in which case you should know that @Service does not work automatically in Jersey.  Instead you would need to add a binding that would do like a bind(MyProductManager).to(ProductManager) in some Jersey binder

Comment: ye, I added the binding but wondering why the @Service doesn't work

Comment: Jersey has made the choice to use explicit bindings over automatic bindings.  This is a perfectly valid choice, as it provides more control to the user, but means that some of the automatic features of hk2 (i.e. @Service) will not work

Comment: is there a way to keep it? as it gives many abilites to play aronund with the code?

Comment: If you have used the hk2-inhabitant-generator to create the inhabitant files at build time (based on the @Service annotation) then you can use code like this to have it automatically read in: `DynamicConfigurationService dcs =locator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
Populator populator = dcs.getPopulator();
populator.populate(new ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder(getClass().getClassLoader());`

Comment: If you have used the hk2-inhabitant-generator to create the inhabitant files at build time  = what does it mean?

Comment: if I would use @Service of Jersey - would it work? cuz I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: To use the automatic facility of hk2 you need to run a step at building that will scan all of your class files for those marked with @Service and add a resource to the jar with (basically) the list of classes.  More information can be found here: [link](https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0/inhabitant-generator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check the package of the `@Contract` in your `ProductManager` interface. Both Jersey ([@Contract](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/spi/Contract.html)) and HK2 ([@Contract](https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0/apidocs/org/jvnet/hk2/annotations/Contract.html)) have annotation with this name.

Make sure to take a look also at Jersey User Guide:

- [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)

Comment: I tried both Jersey annotation and HK2 annotation and it didn't work :(